# How to let a `std::vector<int32_t>` take memory from a `std::vector<uint32_t>&&`?

Tags: c++, c++14, stdvector, move-semantics, reinterpret-cast

```
template<typename T>
struct raster {
    std::vector<T> v;

    template<typename U, typename = std::enable_if_t<sizeof(T) == sizeof(U)>>
    raster(raster<U>&& other){
        // What code goes here?
    }
}
```

Suppose we have `raster<uint32_t> r` such that `r.v.size()` is in the millions, and a guarantee that all its elements are within `int32_t`'s range. Is it possible for `raster<int32_t>::raster(raster<uint32_t>&& other)` to avoid copying the memory backing `other.v`?

Or should I just do something like `*reinterpret_cast<raster<int32_t>*>(&r)` instead of calling that constructor?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Indeed I want to preserve the value of each element. But don't `int32_t` and `uint32_t` have the same representation for integers mutually expressible? (i.e. from [0  2^31-1])

Comment: Is that guaranteed? Nothing in range [2^31, 2^32-1]?

Comment: @JHBonarius The desired behavior is for the stolen memory to be reinterpreted as-is.

Comment: Does this discussion about the types matter if the `size()` (but not the `capacity()`) of the object to be stolen from is zero? Not even the `sizeof` the types matter in this case (but the alignment does): all `vector<T>` holds in this case is raw memory. But there is no legal way to get it.

Comment: @Museful It seems you are right about that ([6.7.1 3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.types#basic.fundamental-3)). It also seems like [type aliasing rules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast#Type_aliasing) make an exception allowed simultaneous `signed` and `unsigned` pointers to the same object. Specifically for fundamental integral types, I can't seem to find a reason this can't conceptually work. Though the interface of `std::vector` won't allow such a thing.

Comment: @Museful there is no portable way to do that, but if `uint32_t` is "compatible with" `int32_t` *and* `vector<uint32_t>` is "compatible with" `vector<int32_t>` -- you can invoke vector's move ctor on `std::move(*reinterpret_cast<vector<T>*>(&other.v))` and it should work. Pretty sure this will work for most popular platforms. Alas, there is no `static_assert` for "sameness" of vector<int32_t> and vector<uint32_t>... If you ever go this way -- you better put huge 2-page comment there...

Comment: @C.M. You can't `reinterpret_cast` a `std::vector<T>` pointer or reference to another `std::vector<U>` pointer or reference unless `T` and `U` are the same type. It's always undefined behavior to dereference the resulting pointer.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux pretty sure I should be able to do it for pointer to `std::vector`

Comment: @C.M. `reinterpret_cast` is only allowed in [these cases](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast#Explanation). None of them allow what you are proposing.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux What about case #5?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174365/discussion-between-francois-andrieux-and-c-m).

Comment: Why do you want to do this thing? It makes no sense. If you merely want to keep allocated memory, then simply write your own custom allocator and use that for either vector, destroy the old one and create the new one, but let your allocator keep the memory.

Answer (score 5):

There is no legal way to do this in C++; you can only move buffers from a `std::vector` to another `std::vector` of the exact same type.

There are a variety of ways you can hack this.  The most illegal and evil would be

```
std::vector<uint32_t> evil_steal_memory( std::vector<int32_t>&& in ) {
  return reinterpret_cast< std::vector<uint32_t>&& >(in);
}
```

or something similar.

A less evil way would be to forget it is a `std::vector` at all.

```
template<class T>
struct buffer {
  template<class A>
  buffer( std::vector<T,A> vec ):
    m_begin( vec.data() ),
    m_end( m_begin + vec.size() )
  {
    m_state = std::unique_ptr<void, void(*)(void*)>(
      new std::vector<T,A>( std::move(vec) ),
      [](void* ptr){
        delete static_cast<std::vector<T,A>*>(ptr);
      }
    );
  }
  buffer(buffer&&)=default;
  buffer& operator=(buffer&&)=default;
  ~buffer() = default;
  T* begin() const { return m_begin; }
  T* end() const { return m_end; }
  std::size_t size() const { return begin()==end(); }
  bool empty() const { return size()==0; }
  T* data() const { return m_begin; }
  T& operator[](std::size_t i) const {
    return data()[i];
  }
  explicit operator bool() const { return (bool)m_state; }

  template<class U>
  using is_buffer_compatible = std::integral_constant<bool,
    sizeof(U)==sizeof(T)
    && alignof(U)==alignof(T)
    && !std::is_pointer<T>{}
  >;
  template<class U,
    std::enable_if_t< is_buffer_compatible<U>{}, bool > = true
  >
  buffer reinterpret( buffer<U> o ) {
    return {std::move(o.m_state), reinterpret_cast<T*>(o.m_begin()),reinterpret_cast<T*>(o.m_end())};
  }
private:
  buffer(std::unique_ptr<void, void(*)(void*)> state, T* b, T* e):
    m_state(std::move(state)),
    m_begin(begin),
    m_end(end)
  {}
  std::unique_ptr<void, void(*)(void*)> m_state;
  T* m_begin = 0;
  T* m_end = 0;
};
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/82a73c2d8091ff2a): this type erases a buffer of `T`.

```
template<class T>
struct raster {
  buffer<T> v;

  template<typename U, typename = std::enable_if_t<sizeof(T) == sizeof(U)>>
  raster(raster<U>&& other):
    v( buffer<T>::reinterpret( std::move(other).v ) )
  {}
};
```

note that my `buffer` has a memory allocation in it; compared to millions of elements that is cheap.  It is also move-only.

The memory allocation can be eliminated through careful use of the small buffer optimization.

I'd leave it move-only (who wants to accidentally copy a million elements?) and maybe write

```
buffer clone() const;
```

which creates a new buffer with the same contents.

Note that instead of a `const buffer<int>` you should use a `buffer<const int>` under the above design.  You can change that by duplicating the `begin() const` methods to have const and non-const versions.

This solution relies on your belief that reinterpreting a buffer of `int32_t`s as a buffer of `uint32_t`s (or vice versa) doesn't mess with anything.  Your compiler may provide this guarantee, but the C++ standard **does not**.

Comment: should the template parameter `T` of the constructor of `buffer<T>` not be named differently? or not be present at all?

Comment: I don't see the benefit of the type-erasure here, you use `std::unique_ptr<void, void(*)(void*)>` to emulate a reinterpret cast, it doesn't provide more safety. And the usual `reinterpret_cast` approach is very common.

Comment: @liliscent I don't reinterpret the `vector` itself, I reinterpret the buffer the vector owns.  The buffer is a pile of plain old data; the vector is an opaque type created by the C++ std library.  I personally find reinterpreting a buffer far less insane than reinterpreting a type within `std`.  It seems *likely* that the binary layout of a `std::vector<uint32_t>` and a `std::vector<int32_t>` is similar, which is why it is *likely* to work, but **nobody** is going to guarantee that.  On the other hand, it is reasonable that a buffer of contiguous `int32_t` and `uint32_t` are identical.

Comment: @Walter Thanks, fixed.  Possibly I should compile my code.  ;)

Comment: @Museful It is deep UB; time travel could occur.  Your code is inlined, and the compiler proves that nobody has modified a `std::vector<int32_t>`.  After all, `evil_steal_memory` only modifies a `vector<uint32_t>`.  So as you checked `.empty()` on a `int32_t` vector 10 lines ago, and we check again in 5 lines, we can skip that check; logically, there was no way for it to become empty without executing undefined behavior.  In short, it is an evil violation of the type system, and those are *dangerous*.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Writing custom wrapper for `std::vector` looks very awkward to me. And the compiler would be insane if `std::vector<uint32_t>` and `std::vector<int32_t>` has different structures... But it's an interesting answer, +1

Comment: @liliscent don't underestimate the compilers ability to notice that "this specific thing you do *here* has UB, thus I can freely do this *other crazy thing* *over here*". As soon as the program invokes UB *anywhere* you've bought yourself a ticket to crazy-land.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I won't underestimate UB, but I won't be obsessed either. Something like this is just *practically safe*, otherwise many code will be broken if compilers deliberately do some crazy stuff. I doubt you haven't written reinterpret cast for `std::vector` before.

Comment: `evil_steal_memory` may be correct (depending on (1) vector implementation (2) compiler vendor). See [this discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174365/discussion-between-francois-andrieux-and-c-m) (most importantly around 14:24 mark)

Comment: Reinterpreting integral types as their signed/unsigned counterparts is implementation-defined behavior. The iffy part is they're an array, which seems practically safe.

Comment: @liliscent It is actually a custom wrapper for an owning contiguous buffer of `T`; you can store a `std::array<T,N>` a `std::string<C,T>` or a raw `T*, size_t` or a `T[N]` in it.  It is similar to `gsl::span<T>`, except it owns its buffer.  I just implemented the vector ctor.

Comment: @PasserBy Yes, the array part is questionable; to be fair, the current status of low level array rules in the C++ standard is horridly broken to the point that implementing a `std::vector` is impossible in-language.

Comment: @liliscent Note that the two vectors can have the same structure and things still blow up: because that cast is a strict aliasing violation, and aliasing is used to prove that values are not modified by currently existing compilers, the risk I see is that the compiler *proves the state of the vector of signed ints was not changed by the `evil_steal_memory`*.  That is a perfectly valid conclusion.  You never modified a `vector<int32_t>` along any path that executes defined behavior; thus it is unmodified.  But it was also modified.  And then your program blows up.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont It's kind of like the consequence of placement `new`, after `evil_steal_memory`, you can't access the underlying object with the old reference. That seems to be a reasonable restriction.

Comment: @liliscent Well, then either destructor doesn't run, or you leak memory.  :)  It is UB all the way down.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the implementation of the vector template itself may be specialised for the type. For some weird whacky reason we don't understand today, the top-level vector might need an extra member not provided in vector, so simply reinterpret casting will not work safely.

Another evil approach might be to look at the Allocator of your two vectors. 
If this was

- a custom allocator you had written and both were a derived class from vector
- and you wrote an overload in the class for swap and =&&
- within which you created wrapped tmp vectors to swap with
- and detected that the Allocator was being called within those temporary objects constructors/destructors, and on the same thread
- to release and reallocate the same sized array

Then, perhaps you could legitimately pass the memory buffer between them without resetting the content.

But that is a lot of fragile work!